# How to read the RxJs mergeMap marble diagram

Tags: javascript, rxjs, marble-diagram

In this marble diagram for [`mergeMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap), how do you read this expression?

```js
// Kind of, looks like an em-dash near the end
mergeMap(i => 10*i--10*i--10*i--|)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mergeMap` maps `i` to an observable represented by the string `10*i--10*i--10*i-|`. This string contains [marble syntax](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/testing/marble-testing#marble-syntax) representing events happening over virtual time.

The main characters used in the documentation are:

> - `-` frame: 1 "frame" of virtual time passing
> - `[a-z0-9]` any alphanumeric character: Represents a value being emitted by the producer signaling `next()`.
> - `|` complete:   The successful completion of an observable. This is the observable producer signaling `complete()`.
> - `#` error: An error terminating the observable. This is the observable producer signaling `error()`.

So `10--10--10-|` would be an expression for the second observable in the picture.
e.g.

```ts
const tens$ = timer(0, 4).pipe(take(3), mapTo(10))
```

`10*i--10*i--10*i-|` is an expression for the observable you get when you multiply every value emitted by `10--10--10-|` with `i`.
e.g.

```ts
of(1,3,5).pipe(
  mergeMap(i => tens$.pipe(map(v => v*i)))
)
```