# Why does mergeMap in RxJS remember history when it's not a ReplaySubject

Tags: rxjs

Two buttons on screen with clicks plumbed in like this.

```
  b1c: number;
  b1s: Subject<number>;
  o1: Observable<number>;
  b2c: number;
  b2s: Subject<number>;
  o2: Observable<number>;


  rxjs(): void {
    this.b1c = 0;
    this.b1s = new Subject<number>()

    this.b2c = 0;
    this.b2s = new Subject<number>()

    this.b1s.pipe(
      tap (z => console.log('do', z)),
      mergeMap(z1 => this.b2s.pipe(
        map(z2 => `${z1} / ${z2}`)
      ))
    ).subscribe(z => console.log(z));

    // When you click button 1 nothing happens.
    // When you click button 2 you get output i/j for all values of i from 0 to current, and the current value of j.
    // This is incorrect because this.b1s is not a ReplaySubject and therefore should not remember the previous values.
  }

  buttonClick(buttonNumber: number) {
    if (buttonNumber === 1) {
      this.b1s.next(this.b1c);
      this.b1c++;
    }
    else {
      this.b2s.next(this.b2c);
      this.b2c++;
    }
  }
```

Can you explain this behaviour? (Button clicks: 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2.)

[image]

It *should* be only

```
5 / 1
6 / 1
7 / 1
```

because 0 to 4 have already been consumed; there is no reason why they should be remembered.

In fact maybe there should be no output at all because at no time do the two observables simultaneously fire -- you can't click two buttons at once.

How do you explain this behaviour, and how is it possible to deduce this from the documentation?

Furthermore: I don't understand why there are three 30s and three 50s and why they're mixed up. There should be six outputs becuase there are six events.
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/flatMap
And we still have this business about it remembering the last value from the other source.

And what on earth is

```
10*i--10*i--10*i-|
```

supposed to mean?

Comment: In your code you have `mergeMap` not `switchMap` as you say in the title

Comment: Edited; although `switchMap` is also completely impenetrable.

Comment: Every time you click `b1s` you're merging another Observable into the chain. So by the time you click `b2s` you've already merge `b2s` 5 times so it's going to make 5 emissions.

Comment: It exactly how  [mergeMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap) work.It merge a recently fired value from b1s, to a serious of values fired from b2s( which remembered by mergeMap). The first click on button 1 isnt doing anything, because nothing fired from b2s yet. It has nothing to do with Replay Subject or Behavior Subject

Comment: Regarding the marble syntax see https://stackoverflow.com/q/64288479/9423231

Answer (score 1):

What you understand as 'remembering history' are just active subscriptions.

`obs1.pipe(mergeMap(v => obs2))` maps each value from the source (`obs1`) to a stream (`obs2`). So you end up with multiple `obs2` streams having an active subscription at the same time. These `obs2` streams are merged in one output stream and run until they complete, error or you unsubscribe.

In your case `obs2 = b2s` is a Subject which is a hot observable that doesn't terminate on its own. The final observables behaves like this:

```ts
this.b1s.pipe(
  mergeMap(z1 => this.b2s.pipe(
    map(z2 => `${z1} / ${z2}`)
  ))
).subscribe(z => console.log(z));


b1s:    --0--1--2--3--4-------5--6--7--------
b2s-7:    │  │  │  │  │       │  │  └--7/1---
b2s-6:    │  │  │  │  │       │  └-----6/1---
b2s-5:    │  │  │  │  │       └--------5/1---
b2s-4:    │  │  │  │  └--4/0-----------4/1---  
b2s-3:    │  │  │  └-----3/0-----------3/1---  
b2s-2:    │  │  └--------2/0-----------2/1---  
b2s-1:    │  └-----------1/0-----------1/1---  
b2s-0:    └--------------0/0-----------0/1---

output: -----------------0/0-----------0/1---
                         1/0           1/1
                         2/0           2/1 
                         3/0           3/1
                         4/0           4/1
                                       5/1
                                       6/1
                                       7/1
```

The subscriptions to `b2s-0` - `b2s-4` are still active when `b2s` emits `1`.

If you don't want the inner streams to run indefinitely you have to terminate them somehow. You could use `take(1)` if you only want them to emit one value.

```ts
this.b1s.pipe(
  mergeMap(z1 => this.b2s.pipe(
    take(1), // <-- only emit 1 value and then complete
    map(z2 => `${z1} / ${z2}`)
  ))
).subscribe(z => console.log(z));


b1s:    --0--1--2--3--4-------5--6--7--------
b2s-7:    │  │  │  │  │       │  │  └--7/1|
b2s-6:    │  │  │  │  │       │  └-----6/1| 
b2s-5:    │  │  │  │  │       └--------5/1|
b2s-4:    │  │  │  │  └--4/0|  
b2s-3:    │  │  │  └-----3/0|  
b2s-2:    │  │  └--------2/0|  
b2s-1:    │  └-----------1/0|  
b2s-0:    └--------------0/0|  

output: -----------------0/0-----------5/1---       
                         1/0           6/1 
                         2/0           7/1 
                         3/0           
                         4/0
```

In the documentation `obs2 = 10----10----10-|` is a cold observable that terminates after 3 emissions. It also generates the same 3 emissions for every subscriber (unlike your Subject).

```ts
ob1:    --1-----------------------------3--------------5----------------------------|
obs2-3:   │                             │              └10*5------10*5------10*5-|
obs2-2:   │                             └10*3------10*3------10*3-| 
obs2-1:   └10*1------10*1------10*1-|

output: ---10*1------10*1------10*1------10*3------10*3-10*5-10*3-10*5------10*5----|
  =     --- 10 ------ 10 ------ 10 ------ 30 ------ 30 - 50 - 30 - 50 ------ 50 ----|
```

Comment: Every time I click b2, b1 replays its entire history. Why? This is completely unexpected.
And why doesn't clicking b1 output anything when both streams have non-empty histories?

Suppose the current values are `b1:10` and `b2: 100`. Then clicking b1 should output `11 / 100` and clicking `b2` should output `10 / 101`.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough `b1` doesn't replay its history. When `b1` emits this value gets mapped to `b2.pipe(map(z2 => '${z1} / ${z2}'))`. This results in a subscription to `b2.pipe(map(z2 => '${z1} / ${z2}'))` but this inner observable doesn't emit anything directly because `b2` doesn't replay its history.  So you end up with multiple subscriptions to `b2.pipe(map(z2 => '${z1} / ${z2}'))` (as many as the times `b1` emits). When `b2` emits `b2.pipe(map(z2 => '${z1} / ${z2}'))` emits. So for every active subscription to `b2.pipe(map(z2 => '${z1} / ${z2}'))` you get an output.